# Where to stop a service during device rotation

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle

When my activity starts, I start a service that fetches data then sends it back to the activity so it can update the UI.

If a config change occurs:

1. If I already have the fetched data, I save it in the `onSaveInstanceState` method.
2. If I haven't received the fetched data, I want to cancel the running service and relaunch it using the new activity.

So my `onSaveInstanceState` currently looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {

    if (data != null) {
        outState.putSerializable(DATA_IN_BUNDLE, data);
    }

    // Stop any data fetching that may be going on.
    stopService(new Intent(this, FetchService.class));
}
```

However, I've noticed that this method is called during the normal starting of the activity, which I didn't know happened, so when it's run the service is always cancelled.

So my questions are:

1. Is this documented somewhere? Couldn't find anywhere that said `onSaveInstanceState` is called during activity start.
2. What would a better place to stop the service be? `onConfigurationChanged`?

Thanks!

Comment: onConfigurationChanged preferred.

Comment: How does the `Service`  send the data back to the `Activity`?

Comment: @DavidWasser via a Messenger https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html

Comment: Is it possible to use Loaders instead? Sounds like a typical problem that Loaders are meant to solve.

Comment: @JeffEngebretsen Interesting, I'd never run into Loaders before. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few choices:

1. Don't allow Android to kill and restart your `Activity`. Manage the config changes yourself. Usually this is pretty simple to do and prevents you from having to deal with stopping and restarting background stuff.
2. Pass the `ServiceConnection` (or whatever you are using as a communication channel to the `Service`) from the old `Activity` instance to the new `Activity` instance by using `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`
3. Use a service-bus architecture, so that one `Activity` can start something and another `Activity` can register for the callback.
4. Send the response from the `Service` to the `Activity` using a broadcast `Intent`, which can be seen by the new `Activity` after a config change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had considered option 1 but thought that was more like a hack or work around. From your experience do you consider it's a good, clean way to solve this?

Comment: Option 1 makes a lot of sense if the `Activity` is holding a persistent connection to some other resource. It isn't a hack, it is perfectly OK.